# How to get the values corresponding to another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and am a bit confused on how I would write a query in order to get the count of state in a different table.

Ie i have this table [student]

| id | school_code |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0123 |
| 1 | 2345 |
| 2 | 2345 |

And this other table [school]

| school_code | name | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0123 | xxyy | New Jersey |
| 2345 | xyxy | Washington |
| 3456 | yxyx | Colarado |

I want to find out how I would get this table which tells me the entries for state by checking each student and making a count of how often that state occurs, ordered by most occurrences in student table.

| State | No. times occured (iterating through student) |
| --- | --- |
| Washington | 2 |
| New Jersey | 1 |

```
SELECT school.state, count(school.state)
FROM student, school
WHERE student.school_code = school.school_code
GROUP BY school.state
ORDER BY count(school.state)`
```

I'm not sure whether this would be iterating through each student and counting them?
Or just natural-joinging student and school and then counting all the states

When I run this on data supplied, the numbers of times occurred is a really low number which doesn't seem right?

Answer (score 0):

We can simply `JOIN` the two tables and `COUNT` the school code in the students table, with `GROUP BY` state:

```
SELECT
sc.state, COUNT(st.school_code)
FROM
school sc
JOIN student st
ON sc.school_code = st.school_code
GROUP BY sc.state;
```

We can try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hBcIBA6o)

Comment: Thank you for the response!


My apologies, I made a typo whilst trying to format, I’ve now edited it again.


Would this still work if the sc.school_code and st.school_code were named differently?

Comment: What do you mean by this question? Of course, you need to select the correct column names. If let's for example say the column "school_code" in the student table is named "code1" and the column "school_code" in the school table is named "code2", you will need to write "ON st.code1=sc.code2" and also replace the column name "st.school_code" with "st.code1" in the column selection before the FROM clause begins.